# Kill a thread in previous activity in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread in Activity A which starts Activity B after 30 seconds.But user can also go to activity B before that time on a button click.I want kill thread in Activity A if the user clicks that button so that Activity B wont get started again. I tried to kill thread if button is clicked, but it is of no use and finish() is also not killing that thread after navigating to B.

```
Thread t=new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {   

            try {
                sleep(5000);
                currentClass = Class.forName("com.crazydna.memorizethepic.Level"+levelNumber);
                Intent ourIntent = new Intent(PictureDisplay.this, currentClass);
                startActivity(ourIntent);
            } 
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("TAG","Error: " +e.getStackTrace());
                //e.printStackTrace();
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(PictureDisplay.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                alertDialog.setMessage(" "+e.toString());
                alertDialog.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.dismiss();                        
                       }
                   });
                alertDialog.show();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(PictureDisplay.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Alert!!!");
                alertDialog.setMessage(" "+e.toString());
                alertDialog.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                           dialog.dismiss();                        
                       }
                   });
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to options.

The first option is to shorten the time for your `sleep()` function and enclose it in a `while()` block where you monitor a cancellation variable, this variable would be in your class definition.

```
Boolean run_my_timer = true;
while (run_my_timer)
{
    sleep(1000); // sleep 1 second only
    currentClass = Class.forName("com.crazydna.memorizethepic.Level"+levelNumber);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(PictureDisplay.this, currentClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
}
```

And add a line that set's this variable to `false` if the user clicks the button

```
run_my_timer = false;
```

This would make the thread exit.

The second option, which would be more elegant is create a [Timer,](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) instead of a thread, if the user presses the button to open ActivityB you cancel the timer, with the Timer's `cancel()` method.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to use Timer?

Comment: There are many tutorials out there. I would end-up copy-pasting the first tutorial I find in google.

Answer (score 1):

just put a boolean variable `isStarted` as instance variable, Check this within thread

```
try {
            sleep(5000);
            if(!isStarted)
            {
                currentClass =               
                Class.forName("com.crazydna.memorizethepic.Level"+levelNumber);
                Intent ourIntent = new Intent(PictureDisplay.this, currentClass);
                startActivity(ourIntent);
            }
    }
```

On button click set `isStarted` to `true`

Comment: @VishwanathL I tried that method already but it is of no use.

Comment: It should work, are you sure that you set the variable true on button click ?

Comment: @VishwanathL Yes, I did that but it is of no use.